# How do I get every minute every voice user in the channel? Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have created this loop function to get every voice user every minute, but it does not work like I thought.

I get every Minute the same result. If I leve the voice Channel it will still show me my username in the console in the next call. It does not update the result.

```
function loop(){
    setTimeout(loop, 60000)

    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        console.log(`Voice users in ${guild.name}:`)
        guild.voiceStates.cache.forEach(voiceState => {
            if(voiceState.channel){
                console.log(voiceState.member.displayName);
            }
            
        });
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `GUILD_VOICE_STATES` in your client's intents. Otherwise the client is not receiving `VOICE_STATE_UPDATE` event.

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES"] });
```

For a complete list of intents and what they do see [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents).